# Place Autocomplete API delivers fewer results than Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I use the Place Autocomplete API (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete) trying to get the same results as in Google Maps. Until a few days ago the result where pretty the same, but now they differ significantly: In Google Maps I get the same results as before, but in Place Autocomplete API sometimes I don't get even one result anymore.
Example: Using https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=wanko%20ainring&language=de&components=country:de&key=mykey I get zero results. Typing in "wanko ainring" in Google Maps I get one result with an address.
Has something internally changed in the Place Autocomplete API or am I doing something wrong?

Or maybe I should generally ask: How do I get the same results in Place Autocomplete API as in Google Maps?

Thanks for any comment.

Comment: You specifies language and components parameter in your request URL, these parameter will restrict the search, they might reduce the results from you API request.

Comment: Thanks, ztan. but when I remove the language and components parameters, I still get zero results.